# Quick one about SET

Tags: php, mysqli

Got a quick question

I have this

```
UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 6 WHERE stats.id=$id4
```

Is it possible, assuming I have playerrank set as VARCHAR in the database, to exchange the number to a string?

So it would be like this

```
UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = God WHERE stats.id=$id4
```

Comment: Yes... **but** you will need to quote it `SET stats.playerrank = 'God'`

Comment: if set to varchar just enclose with single '

Comment: If you're using MySQLi (as indicated by your tags), then use bind variables

Answer (score 2):

You are going to run into issues unless you put `God` in single quotes.  Setting a VARCHAR expects this syntax:

```
UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 'God' WHERE stats.id=$id4
```

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question c: